# measure theory: show that the integral of a type of "step function" is the sum of the heights of the "steps"

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers.  Define the function $f$ on $E = [1, \infty)$ by setting $f(x) = a_n$ if $n \leq x < n+1$.

Show that $\int_E f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$

What I have so far is this:

$f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \chi[n, n+1]$

And I know I will need to justify somehow that the limit of the integral of this is equal to the integral of the limit, which is equal to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$, but I'm just not sure how to show it rigorously.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n=\sum_{I=1}^{I=n}a_n\chi_{[n,n+1)}$.  $Sup_nf_n=f $ and $f_n$ is increasing. You can apply Beppo Levi.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Beppo_Levi%27s_Theorem